# Function returning None with pyper

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pyper

I tried to create a function for the following

```
from pyper import *
import pandas as pd

r=R(use_pandas=True)
r.assign('xN', 5)
r.assign('yN', 3)
r('out1 <- xN + yN')
print(r.get('out1'))
8
```

created function

```
def addR(x, y):
    r=R(use_pandas=True)
    r.assign('xR', x)
    r.assign('yR', y)
    return r('out <- xR + yR')

addR(5, 3)
r=R(use_pandas=True)
print(r.get('out'))
None
```

is returning None

Comment: This is confusing. This is running in python? I'm not sure why you're calling `get()` on the output

Comment: You'll have to get a better understanding of variables scopes ... the `r` you are defining in the function is lost, the one you are printing is a new and empty one. Maybe you would like to do something like `r=addR(5, 3);print(r.get('out'))`